# drawString() Displays a Random Integer strangely

Tags: java, random

I was making a random line generator for fun, and when I run the program, the "Y (End): " string looks very strange. The numbers are displayed as rectangular symbols, that have no meaning.

Here is my code:

```
public class LineFractal extends Applet {
Random random = new Random();
int width = 640;
int height = 640;
int x = 1000;
int endy1 = random.nextInt(width/2);
int endx1 = random.nextInt(width/2);
int starty1 = random.nextInt(width/2);
int startx1 = random.nextInt(width/2);
int space = random.nextInt(25);
public void init() {
    setSize(width, height);
    Frame c = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    c.setTitle("Line Generator");
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    while (x > 0) {
        x -= 1;
        g.drawLine(startx1, starty1, endx1, endy1);
        g.drawString("Space: " + space, width-100, height-10);
        g.drawString("Y (End): " + endy1, width-100, height-20);
        endy1 += space;
        endx1 -= space;
    }
}
}
```

Why does it do this?

EDIT: Just tried the program again, and the y was actually displayed correctly for once. But then I ran it again, and only the last number could be seen. The last time I ran it, there were no numbers that were readable...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be printing the string `Y (End)` and then a number over the top of itself 1000 times. Obviously that's OK for the text, but the number part is going to look messy very quickly! Imagine writing 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 all on top of each other.

You probably mean to draw a white (or whatever background colour) filled rectangle to the area where the strings are to be printed, just to clear what's there already.

Comment: The "space" string is displayed correctly. Is that because it is a smaller number?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the two `drawString()` outside the `while` loop.